# 2D Scene is not responsive according to screen sizes

Tags: three.js, 2d, responsive, scene, orthographic

I was building a 2D Scene in three.js using orthographic camera and placed the Sprites for the HUD part inside the Scene only so that i cant be changed from html.
I have added everything of the HUD in the cameragroup along with the camera and the cameragroup in the scene. Am moving the cameraGroup for the HUD to stay in its place only. But the problem is that it is not responsive according to different screen sizes. Is there any way like it was in some of the Game engines like cocos and unity to add a widget as a component and it handles multi resolution automattically?

Need Responsive Design for 2D Scene in threejs.